# Scraping a JSON response with Scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

How do you use Scrapy to scrape web requests that return JSON? For example, the JSON would look like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": "10021"
    },
    "phoneNumber": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "646 555-4567"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would be looking to scrape specific items (e.g. `name` and `fax` in the above) and save to csv.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's the same as using Scrapy's `HtmlXPathSelector` for html responses. The only difference is that you should use `json` module to parse the response:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    ...


    def parse(self, response):
         jsonresponse = json.loads(response.text)

         item = MyItem()
         item["firstName"] = jsonresponse["firstName"]             

         return item
```

Comment: You may want to use `json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())` as loads requires a `str` or `unicode` object, not a scrapy Response.

Comment: folks, so now you have parsed a json response.  how would i follow each link that is potentially in the json?

Comment: @Cmag you would need to `return` or `yield` a `Request`, see more info [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions).

Comment: Using an ujson will be more effective

Comment: response.text is preferred over body_as_unicode(), see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.body_as_unicode

Comment: MyItem() is not defined?

Answer (score 21):

Don't need to use `json` module to parse the reponse object.

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
...


def parse(self, response):
     jsonresponse = response.json()

     item = MyItem()
     item["firstName"] = jsonresponse.get("firstName", "")           

     return item
```

Comment: I think this would be better as a comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: I need "50 reputation" to comment, so I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason JSON is not loading is that it has single-quotes before and after. Try this:

```
json.loads(response.body_as_unicode().replace("'", '"'))
```

Comment: Also can be a strange json, e.g. with unnecessary brackets, then use: `json.loads(response.body_as_unicode().strip('()'))`.