# Scrapy: How can I parse a JSON response?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I have a [spider](http://pastebin.com/J3ZiTLxh) (click to see the source) that works perfectly for regular html page scraping.
However, I want to add an additional feature. I would like to parse a JSON page.

Here is what I want to do (Here it is done manually, without scrapy):

```
import requests, json
import datetime

def main():
    user_agent = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36'
    }

    # This is the URL that outputs JSON:
    externalj = 'http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/externaljson.php?&s='
    # Form the end of the URL, it is based on the time (unixtime):

    past = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
    time = past.strftime('%s')
    # This is the full URL:
    url = externalj + time

    # Make the HTTP get request:
    tsr_data = requests.get(url, headers= user_agent).json()

    # Iterate over the json data and form the URLs 
    # (there are no URLs at all in the JSON data, they must be formed manually):

    # URL is formed simply by concatenating the canonical link with a thread-id:

    for post in tsr_data['discussions-recent']:
        link= 'www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t='
        return link + post['threadid']
```

This function will return proper links to the HTML pages (links to forum threads) that I want to scrape. It seems I will need to create my own request object to send to `parse_link` in the [spider](http://pastebin.com/J3ZiTLxh)?

**My question is, where do I put this code? I am very confused as to how to incorporate this into scrapy? Do I need to create another spider?**

Ideally, I would like it to work with [the spider that I already have](http://pastebin.com/J3ZiTLxh), not sure if that is possible though.

Very confused as to how to implement this in scrapy. I hope someone can advise!

My current spider is this:

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import TsrItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class TsrSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'tsr'
    allowed_domains = ['thestudentroom.co.uk']

    start_urls = ['http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/forumdisplay.php?f=89']

    download_delay = 2
    user_agent = 'youruseragenthere'

    thread_xpaths = ("//tr[@class='thread  unread    ']",
            "//*[@id='discussions-recent']/li/a",
            "//*[@id='discussions-popular']/li/a")

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('showthread\.php\?t=\d+',),
            restrict_xpaths=thread_xpaths),
        callback='parse_link', follow=True),]

    def parse_link(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//li[@class='post threadpost old   ']"):
            item = TsrItem()
            item['id'] = sel.xpath(
"div[@class='post-header']//li[@class='post-number museo']/a/span/text()").extract()
            item['rating'] = sel.xpath(
"div[@class='post-footer']//span[@class='score']/text()").extract()
            item['post'] = sel.xpath(
"div[@class='post-content']/blockquote[@class='postcontent restore']/text()").extract()
            item['link'] = response.url
            item['topic'] = response.xpath(
"//div[@class='forum-header section-header']/h1/span/text()").extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: Have you seen [this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171835/scraping-a-json-response-with-scrapy)? Perhaps it might answer your question.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. Just this cannot be incorporated with my current spider. According to the docs, CrawlSpider's parse method should not be changed.

Answer (score 2):

It *seems* I have found a way to make it work. And maybe my original post was not clear.

I wanted to parse a JSON Response and then send a Request to be further processed by scrapy.

I added the following to my Spider:

```
# A request object is required.
from scrapy.http import Request
```

And:

```
def parse_start_url(self, response):
    if  'externaljson.php' in str(response.url):
        return self.make_json_links(response)
```

`parse_start_url` seems to do as it says. It parses the inital urls (start urls). Only the JSON page should be processed here.

Because of this I needed to add my special JSON url with my html urls:

```
start_urls = ['http://tsr.com/externaljson.php', 'http://tsr.com/thread.html']
```

I now need to generate the URLs, in the form of a Request, from the JSON page's reponse:

```
def make_json_links(self, response):
    ''' Creates requests from JSON page. '''
    data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    for post in data['discussions-recent']:
        link = 'http://www.tsr.co.uk/showthread.php?t='
        full_link = link + str(post['threadid'])
        json_request = Request(url=full_link)
        return json_request
```

And now it seems to work. However, I am sure this is a hacky and inelegant way to accomplish this. It feels wrong somehow.

It appears to work and it follows all of the links I made from the JSON page. I am also not sure if I should've used a `yield` instead of a `return` somewhere in there...

Answer (score 0):

Do the links always follow the same format? Would it not be possible to create a new Rule for the JSON links, with a separate `parse_json` function used as the callback?

Comment: The links follow the same format. But there are no links on the JSON page itself.