# Scrapy for dynamic content

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Can we use Scrapy for getting content from a web page which is loaded by Javascript?

I'm trying to scrape usage examples from [this](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/unalienable) page,
but since they are loaded using Javascript as a JSON object I'm not able to get them with Scrapy.

Could you suggest what is the best way to deal with such issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your browser's developer tools and look at the Network tab. If you hit the "next" button on that page enough, it'll send out a new request:

[image: examples.json]

After removing the JSONP paramter, the URL is pretty straightforward:

```
https://corpus.vocabulary.com/api/1.0/examples.json?query=unalienable&maxResults=24&startOffset=24&filter=0
```

By making the minimal number of requests, your spider will be fast.

If you want to just emulate a full browser and execute the JavaScript, you can use something like Selenium or [Scrapinghub's Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) (and its corresponding Scrapy [plugin](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)).

Comment: I got that url but it returns a text file which again I'm able to scrap using scrappy. I want to extract the sentences from the file. How can I do that?
PS-Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: It's JSON. Parse it with `json.loads`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171835/scraping-a-json-response-with-scrapy

Comment: I already tried that, it returns error ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

Comment: I don't know how! but it worked after I restarted the scrapy shell. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: can you explain why you removed JSONP parameter from URL?

Comment: Because JSONP isn't JSON and wouldn't be parsed by a JSON parser. Leave it in and see what happens.

Comment: i did that first and it was not getting parsed then i removed it and then i was able to parse the response with json object